# when resizing a image set only resizing one image

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv

When I was trying to resize an image set, it was only resizing the first image.How to resize all images? This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
pic_num = 1
img = cv2.imread("E:\ele/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
resized_image = cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
cv2.imwrite("E:\eye/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg',resized_image)
pic_num += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looping through files and change it, and don't worried about time.

then you can just use for loop in python

For example you have pics from 1 too 100

Then you can just do following:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

for pic_num in range(1,100):
    img = cv2.imread("E:\ele/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
    cv2.imwrite("E:\eye/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg',resized_image)
```

Comment: It gives an error called "expected an indented block", in the 6th line coloring in red the word "img". How to solve that?